# Where do i find my username?

Tags: wallet

A website is wanting my username & screenshot of my bit wallet so they cand me my Bit coin.
I've looked everywhere in settings.
Thanks

Comment: That information (username, wallet screenshot) is absolutely not required to send bitcoin, all you should need to provide them with is a valid bitcoin address that they can send your coins to. Without more information about your situation, this sounds like it could potentially be a scam of some sort.

Comment: Thank u...it's a casino.

Comment: It's probably a fake casino run by criminals who want to trick you into doing something foolish that will let them steal your money. Or maybe the people asking for the screenshot don't work for the casino. I'm betting on the first.